# Fantasy novel: Standing stones in Cornwall, England. A girl and a violin

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a fantasy novel that I believe takes place in Cornwall, England. It features the [Mên-an-Tol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%AAn-an-Tol), a violin, and music. The protagonist is a girl who passes through one of the circular stones and is transported to another place or time.
That's about all I can remember, except that it made quite an impression on me years ago!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like Charles de Lint's *The Little Country*.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/186445.The_Little_Country) (emphasis mine):

> When folk musician Janey Little finds a mysterious manuscript in an old trunk in her grandfather's cottage, she is swept into a dangerous realm both strange and familiar. But true magic lurks within the pages of The Little Country, drawing genuine danger from across the oceans into Janey's life, impelling her--armed only with her music--toward a terrifying confrontation.
>
> **Come walk the mist-draped hills of Cornwall, come walk the ancient standing stones. Listen to the fiddles,** and the wind, and the sea. Come step with Janey Little into the pages of...The Little Country.

I found it by Googling "fantasy novel Cornwall standing stones", which led me to [this page](http://www.librarything.com/topic/177690).

Comment: Thanks SO much,I googled and googled,but all the wrong words apparently! You made my day!

Comment: @BradScharf You're very welcome! Don't forget to click the checkmark on the left of the answer, to mark your question as solved :-) Actually this book sounds right up my street - I may try to get hold of it and read it myself.

Comment: Rand al'Thor,I remember being very sad when I finished the book. I've always been fascinated with standing stones,the Celts and Druids,elves and faeries,Findhorn,Pan,etc. This book ticked a lot of those boxes. Anyway,thanks again,I just ordered it on Amazon for 69 cents+4.00 shipping. Saw quite a few copies there if you're interested. Cheers Mate! Brad